# Linker error when trying to build apk for arm64

Tags: android-ndk, arm64

Im trying to rebuild an old app (originally armeabi) to support arm64. The current NDK is android-ndk-r10e-windows-x86_64. I have to use this NDK version. Other NDK versions will break current code.

I changed app level build.gradle from

```
abiFilters "armeabi"
```

to

```
abiFilters "armeabi",'arm64-v8a'
```

However when I try to build for the first time, i got error:
C:/Users/user/Documents/android_studio/app/src/main/jni/gameswf/base/tu_timer.cpp:8:38: fatal error: sys/timeb.h: No such file or directory
 #include  // for ftime()

It seems that in the android-ndk-r10e, the file timeb.h is removed. I had no idea of how to fix it, so I manually copied "platforms\android-14\arch-x86\usr\include\sys\timeb.h" to "platforms\android-21\arch-arm64\usr\include\sys\timeb.h" then try again, and I got below error:

C:/Users/user/Documents/android_studio/app/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/release/obj/local/arm64-v8a/objs/native-lib/gameswf/base/tu_timer.o: In function `tu_timer::init_timer()':
C:/Users/user/Documents/android_studio/app/src/main/jni/gameswf/base/tu_timer.cpp:15: undefined reference to`ftime'
C:/Users/user/Documents/android_studio/app/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/release/obj/local/arm64-v8a/objs/native-lib/gameswf/base/tu_timer.o: In function `tu_timer::get_ticks()':
C:/Users/user/Documents/android_studio/app/src/main/jni/gameswf/base/tu_timer.cpp:21: undefined reference to`ftime'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

app level build.gradle

```
defaultConfig {
    //applicationId "applicationId"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 26

    // Enabling multidex support.
    multiDexEnabled true

    ndk {
        moduleName "native-lib"
        //abiFilters "armeabi"
        abiFilters "armeabi",'arm64-v8a'
    }
}
```

Application.mk

```
APP_PLATFORM := android-9
APP_STL := gnustl_static
APP_ABI := all

#APP_OPTIM := debug
APP_OPTIM := release

ifeq ($(APP_OPTIM),debug)
  APP_CPPFLAGS := -O0 -g $(APP_CPPFLAGS)
else
  APP_CPPFLAGS := -O2 -DNDEBUG -g $(APP_CPPFLAGS)
endif
```

I don't know what to do next. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

Android doesn't support `ftime`. Use `gettimeofday` instead. See the [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/ftime.3.html).

> 4.2BSD, POSIX.1-2001.  POSIX.1-2008 removes the specification of
> ftime().
>
> This function is obsolete.  Don't use it.  If the time in seconds
> suffices, time(2) can be used; gettimeofday(2) gives microseconds;
> clock_gettime(2) gives nanoseconds but is not as widely available.